# Better debugging: expected a character buffer object

Tags: python, debugging, buffer

I am trying to pass a string section to the the python function below it 
I am uncertain why I am seeing this error. My understanding of this is that it is not getting a string, where it is expected. I have tried casting, but that is not working either. How can I solve this or get more debug info?

```
section = str('[log]')
some_var = 'filename ='

edit_ini('./bench_config.ini', section, some_var, 'logs/ops_log_1')
```

The function causing the error

```
def edit_ini(filename, section, some_var, value):

    section = False

    flist = open(filename, 'r').readlines()

    f = open(filename+'test', 'w')

    for line in flist:
            line = str(line)
            print line
            if line.startswith(section):
                    section = True
                    if( section == True ):
                            if( line.startswith(some_var) ):
                                    modified = "%s = $s", variable, value
                                    print >> f, modified
                            section = False
            else:
                    print >> f, line
    f.close()
```

However I see the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bench.py", line 89, in <module>
    edit_ini('./config.ini', section, some_var, 'logs/log_1')
  File "bench.py", line 68, in edit_ini
    if line.startswith(section):
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite the passed-in `section` with `section=False`.  The error is because you cannot call `string.startswith( False )`.

A way to debug python is to use [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html).  This would have helped you find your problem here.  You should read the spec, but heres a quick guide on how to use pdb.

```
import pdb
# your code ...
pdb.set_trace() # put this right before line.startswith(section)
```

Then when you run your code, you will execute up to right before the failure.  Then you can print `section` in pdb, and see that it is `False`, and then try to figure out why it is `False`.